# AngularJS binding does not work,when attribute is changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created a directive, which has an isolated-scope:

```
.directive('title',function(){
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope:{
            text:'@'
        },
        replace:true,
        template:'<div>{{text}}</div>',
        link:function(scope,iElement,iAttrs){
        }
    };
})
```

When I am trying to change `"text"` attribute by `.attr` method, the binding does not work. I have tried to use `$apply` method, but without any success.

What is wrong?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6yNN2/)

PS: Pls, do not suggest any solution with using controller and binding the `text` attribute to `$scope`'s properties(something like a `<title text="{{somepropertyincontrollersscope}}">...`). My problem is *only* related to changing the attribute **externally**.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to do it in the `link` function by watching the value of the attribute:

```
scope.$watch(function () {
    return iElement.attr("text");
}, function (newVal) {
    scope.text = newVal;
});
```

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6yNN2/1/).